# How to kill specific VBScript using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to kill specific VBScript using batch file?

```
@echo off
set vbs="%temp%\dummy.vbs"

for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%s in (`WMIC path Win32_Process where 'name="wscript.exe"' get commandline,processid | findstr /i /c:"%vbs%"`) do (
    taskkill /f /fi "pid eq %%s"
)
```

I also tried the code below but it seems that **commandline like** is not working.

```
WMIC path Win32_Process where "name='wscript.exe' and commandline like %vbs%" get processid
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use single quotes to enclose the command **and** use it also inside the command, I'd switch to enclose the command with backquotes and insert `usebackq` --> `for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%s in (\`WMIC path Win32_Process where 'name="wscript.exe"' ...`

Comment: The 'like' syntax, whilst correct in a Command Prompt, requires the `%` characters doubling in a batch file; e.g. `@WMIC Process Where "Name='wscript.exe' And CommandLine Like '%%vbs%%'" Call Terminate 2>Nul`

Comment: `set vbs="%temp%\dummy.vbs"` is not right. Right is `set "vbs=%temp%\dummy.vbs"`. It makes a big difference if first double quote is left to variable name or right to equal sign. For details see [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Comment: Thanks guys! I was able to make it work with your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporated items in the comments and escaped special characters with **^**.

```
@echo off

set "vbs=%temp%\dummy.vbs"

for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%s in (
    `WMIC process where "name='wscript.exe'" get commandline^,processid ^| findstr /i /c:"%%vbs%%"`
) do (
    taskkill /f /fi "pid eq %%s"
)
```